# How to restrict $_SESSION[] using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, session

I wanna get just  $_SESSION["yetki"] value when I call users function actually I am getting value but always getting "manager" value even if user equal student .

```
 <script>
    function users(tik) {
        var user = tik.id;
        if(user === "student")
        {   
            <?php $_SESSION["yetki"]="student";   echo $_SESSION["yetki"];  ?>
        } 
        else ()
        {
            <?php $_SESSION["yetki"]="manager";   echo $_SESSION["yetki"];  ?>
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is completly wrong, you are mixing both client side and server side code, javascript is client side code and php is server side language. In your `if else` condition you need to send request to server to set that session variable. For sending request to server you can use ajax.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But So far I used many times  php in javascript. I did not get any problem about client side and server side.

Comment: @HAKANMAZI then you where lucky that it _worked_. The `php` code will be executed on the server before send to the client where the js code executed. The php code is not aware of the `if` clause of js and as of that session is always `manager`.

Comment: Probably you are right bro, So I think I have to learn ajax, Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you got all your fundamental understanding of Php and JavaScript wrong. By the time that this script is already running in the client's web browser, the Php scripts would have been processed/executed already and echoed into the document body.

Here's how it works. When you ask for a Php "page", the server would execute every Php script in that page and generate a response. That response would be the one that your web browser would execute.

for example, if you do this:

```
<script>
if (<?Php echo "true"; ?>) { alert ( 'The server said true' ); }
else { alert ( 'The server didn't say anything' ); }
</script>
```

The one you'll see in your web browser is:

```
<script>
if (true) { alert ( 'The server said true' ); }
else { alert ( 'The server didn't say anything' ); }
</script>
```

What Php does is to create dynamic contents for the webpage and send it back to the client. The client's web browser would then execute the result of that generated content. The Php codes would all be executed as soon as you requested for the web page - the process all happens in the server. JavaScript, on the other hand, would execute AFTER the client receives the web page.

In fact, "echo" is a pretty descriptive term of what Php does. When you type a web address in your browser's address bar and press enter, you are sending a request to the server. Once it "hits" the server, it will "echo" a response in the form of HTML. That HTML would then be read by your web browser and that would include everything from Javascript to CSS. And yes, you can even echo a whole mix of HTML elements and Javascript content. You can even echo the whole document body.

for example:

```
<?Php
echo
<<<YOURCONTENT
<HTML>
<HEAD></HEAD>
<BODY>You're gonna love my body.</BODY>
</HTML>
YOURCONTENT;
?>
```

WHAT YOU SHOULD DO FIRST is to validate what the contents of $_SESSION["yetki"] would be.

```
<?Php
if(your conditions here)
$_SESSION["yetki"]="student";
else
$_SESSION["yetki"]="manager";
?>
<script>
function users(tik) {
   var user = tik.id;
   if(user === "student")
   {   
       alert('<?php echo $_SESSION["yetki"];  ?>');
   } 
   else
   {   // I DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU'RE TRYING HERE, BUT LET'S DO AN ALERT.
       alert('<?php echo $_SESSION["yetki"];  ?>');
   }
}
</script>
```

possible conditions for Php if statement:

```
$_POST['yourFormInputName'] == 'yourRogueValue'
```

or

```
$_GET['yourURLVariableName'] == 'yourRogueValue'
```

or

```
$_SESSION['perhapsAnotherStoredSession'] == 'yourRogueValue'
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do with something like this.. but don't know is this a good answer

```
<script>
function users(tik) {
    var user = tik.id;
    if(user === "student")
    {   
        var aa = "<?php $_SESSION["yetki"]="student";   echo $_SESSION["yetki"];  ?>"
    } 
    else
    {
        var aa = "<?php $_SESSION["yetki"]="manager";   echo $_SESSION["yetki"];  ?>"
    }
    alert(aa);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, yes this is right when user equal student, alert gives me student in client side but when I use $_SESSION["yetki"] in server side(php) I am getting manager again and again. I dont know also ajax and So I really dont know How can I fix this  :)

Comment: It is better to call a ajax and set session in ajax php page.